# Add two numbers to each element of a vector

Tags: r

I have a vector and to each element of the vector I want to add more than one number, e.g. 0 and 1, in alternating order.

For example, from the sequence `0,1,2,3,4,5` I want to get `0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6` by first adding 0 and then 1 to each element, successively.

```
a <- c(0:5)
c(a+0, a+1) # does not give me what I want
```

What I actually hope to solve with this is that I want to extract elements from a vector for which a statement is true PLUS THE ELEMENT AFTER THAT, irrespective of whether the statement would be true for that line.

Maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: For your ultimate goal, you can probably do something like `x[head(x==5, -1) & tail(x == 5, -1)]`, altering the `x==5` to fit whatever tests you want. Note that the final element will not be extracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler implementation of Aramis7d's idea uses the each argument to `rep`.

```
rep(1:5, each=2) + 0:1
 [1] 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to interlace you can use `rbind` with `c`

```
a <- c(0:5)
c(rbind(a+0,a+1))
```

For the later question, I would use `which` statement to get the indices of True based on the condition and then get the corresponding elements.

Answer (score 1):

To address your actual question, which is "to extract elements from a vector for which a statement is true PLUS THE ELEMENT AFTER THAT", you might be able to solve that as follows:

Let's say the condition is that a number is equal to 1, and you want to extract those elements, plus the element after it:

```
a <- c(1,2,4,1,2,4,1,2,4)
condition = a==1
condition_shifted = c(FALSE,head(condition,-1))
a[condition | condition_shifted]
```

which returns:

```
[1] 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback lmo appreciated. I modified my answer. I am aware of operator precedence, but it's indeed a mistake that is easily made and can easily be prevented with using head or tail..

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
as.vector(sapply(a, function (x) rep(x,2))) + c(0,1)
```

which gives:

```
 [1] 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6
```